ReferenceError: navigator is not defined in npm run build , despite am using "client side"
in my nextjs project everything working fine while npm run dev but when i try to run npm run build am getting this error in about 70% of my pages ..here is the error:
Error occurred prerendering page "/saloon-services". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at i.tv [as instanceFactory] (E:\Projects\salonhub\old_admin\.next\server\chunks\3070.js:3919:474)
    at a.getOrInitializeService (E:\Projects\salonhub\old_admin\.next\server\chunks\3070.js:189:2773)
    at a.getImmediate (E:\Projects\salonhub\old_admin\.next\server\chunks\3070.js:189:724)
    at tT (E:\Projects\salonhub\old_admin\.next\server\chunks\3070.js:3949:179)
    at 17477 (E:\Projects\salonhub\old_admin\.next\server\app\_not-found\page.js:1:3461)
    at t (E:\Projects\salonhub\old_admin\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at 43059 (E:\Projects\salonhub\old_admin\.next\server\app\_not-found\page.js:1:3605)
    at Object.t [as require] (E:\Projects\salonhub\old_admin\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at require (E:\Projects\salonhub\old_admin\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:18490)
    at I (E:\Projects\salonhub\old_admin\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:94362)

and here is the page that got this erorr /saloon-services :
'use client'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

import {
  getFirestore,
  doc,
  getDoc,
  query,
  collection,
  where,
  getDocs,
  setDoc,
  addDoc,
  deleteDoc
} from 'firebase/firestore'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage'
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid'
import CircularProgress from '@mui/material/CircularProgress'
import Card from '@mui/material/Card'
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField'
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal'
import Box from '@mui/material/Box'
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem'
import Select from '@mui/material/Select'

const modalStyle = {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '50%',
  left: '50%',
  transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  width: 600,
  bgcolor: 'background.paper',
  border: '2px solid #000',
  boxShadow: 24,
  p: 4
}

const SaloonServices = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [saloon, setSaloon] = useState(null)
  const [saloonID, setSaloonID] = useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [services, setServices] = useState([])
  const [selectedService, setSelectedService] = useState(null)
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false)
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]) // New state for categories
  const [selectedCategoryId, setSelectedCategoryId] = useState('') // State to store selected category ID

  const [newService, setNewService] = useState({
    details_ar: '',
    details_en: '',
    highlights_ar: '',
    highlights_en: '',
    image: '',
    category: {
      name_en: '',
      name_ar: '',
      icon: ''
    },
    for_male: false,
    for_female: false,
    starting_price: 0,
    min_time_mins: 0,
    max_time_mins: 0
  })

  const [imageFile, setImageFile] = useState(null)

  const fetchSalonDetails = async () => {
    try {
      const db = getFirestore()
      const auth = getAuth()
      const currentUser = auth.currentUser

      if (!currentUser) {
        throw new Error('No authenticated user found')
      }

      const userDocRef = doc(db, 'User', currentUser.uid)
      const userDoc = await getDoc(userDocRef)

      if (!userDoc.exists()) {
        throw new Error('User not found')
      }

      const salonsQuery = query(collection(db, 'salons'), where('owner', '==', userDocRef))
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(salonsQuery)

      if (querySnapshot.empty) {
        throw new Error('Salon not found')
      }

      const salonDoc = querySnapshot.docs[0]
      const salonData = salonDoc.data()

      setSaloon(salonData)
      setSaloonID(salonDoc.id)
      fetchServices(salonDoc.id)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error fetching salon details:', err)
      setError(err.message)
      setIsLoading(false)
    }
  }

  const fetchServices = async salonId => {
    try {
      const db = getFirestore()

      console.log('fetching saloon service for the saloon with id : ', salonId)

      const salonServicesQuery = query(
        collection(db, 'salon_services'),
        where('salon', '==', doc(db, 'salons', salonId))
      )

      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(salonServicesQuery)

      if (querySnapshot.empty) {
        setServices([])
      } else {
        const servicesData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
          const data = doc.data()

          return {
            id: doc.id, // Ensure the ID is correctly assigned
            ...data // Spread the rest of the data
          }
        })

        console.log(servicesData) // Check the output in the console
        setServices(servicesData) // Update the state with the services data
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to fetch services:', error)
      setError(error.message)
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false)
    }
  }

  const fetchCategories = async () => {
    try {
      const db = getFirestore()
      const categoriesQuery = query(collection(db, 'services'))
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(categoriesQuery)

      const categoriesData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
        id: doc.id,
        name_en: doc.data().name_en,
        name_ar: doc.data().name_ar
      }))

      setCategories(categoriesData)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to fetch categories:', error)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSalonDetails()
    fetchCategories() // Fetch categories when the component mounts
  }, [])

  const handleOpenModal = (service = null) => {
    setSelectedService(service)
    setNewService({
      id: service ? service.id : '', // Access and set the service ID
      details_ar: service ? service.details_ar : '',
      details_en: service ? service.details_en : '',
      highlights_en: service ? service.highlights_en : '',
      highlights_ar: service ? service.highlights_ar : '',
      starting_price: service ? service.starting_price : 0,
      min_time_mins: service ? service.min_time_mins : 0,
      max_time_mins: service ? service.max_time_mins : 0
    })
    setImageFile(null) // Reset image file
    // setSelectedCategoryId(service ? service.category.id : '') // Set the selected category ID
    setModalOpen(true)
  }

  const handleCloseModal = () => {
    setSelectedService(null)
    setNewService({
      name: '',
      description: '',
      image: '',
      category: { name_en: '', name_ar: '', icon: '' },
      for_male: false,
      for_female: false,
      starting_price: 0,
      min_time_mins: 0,
      max_time_mins: 0
    })
    setImageFile(null) // Reset image file
    setSelectedCategoryId('') // Reset selected category ID
    setModalOpen(false)
  }

  const handleImageChange = e => {
    const file = e.target.files[0]

    if (file) {
      setImageFile(file)
    }
  }

  const handleSaveService = async () => {
    try {
      const db = getFirestore()

      console.log('before service Data')

      const serviceData = {
        details_en: newService.details_en,
        details_ar: newService.details_ar,
        highlights_ar: newService.highlights_ar,
        highlights_en: newService.highlights_en,
        starting_price: newService.starting_price,
        min_time_mins: newService.min_time_mins,
        max_time_mins: newService.max_time_mins,
        service: doc(db, 'services', selectedCategoryId),
        salon: doc(db, 'salons', saloonID)
      }

      console.log('after service Data', serviceData)
      console.log('saloon id is :', saloonID)

      console.log(serviceData)

      if (selectedService) {
        // Update existing service
        await setDoc(doc(db, 'salon_services', selectedService.id), serviceData)
      } else {
        // Add new service with auto-generated ID
        await addDoc(collection(db, 'salon_services'), serviceData)
      }

      fetchServices(saloonID)
      handleCloseModal()
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to save service:', error)
    }
  }

  const handleDeleteService = async id => {
    try {
      const db = getFirestore()

      await deleteDoc(doc(db, 'salon_services', id)) // Mark service as deleted or remove it
      fetchServices(saloonID)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to delete service:', error)
    }
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100vh' }}>
        <CircularProgress />
      </div>
    )
  }

  if (error) {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100vh' }}>
        <Typography color='error'>{error}</Typography>
      </div>
    )
  }

  if (!saloon) {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100vh' }}>
        <Typography>No salon data available</Typography>
      </div>
    )
  }

  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    return (
      <Grid container style={{ height: '100vh', padding: 20 }} direction='column' alignItems='center'>
        <Card style={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: 800, padding: 20 }}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography variant='h5' gutterBottom>
              Salon Services
            </Typography>
            <Button variant='contained' color='primary' onClick={() => handleOpenModal()}>
              Add New Service
            </Button>
            <Grid container spacing={2} style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
              {services.map(service => (
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} key={service.id}>
                  <Card>
                    <CardContent>
                      <Typography variant='h6'>{service.service.name_en}</Typography>
                      <Typography variant='body2'>{service.details_en}</Typography>
                      <Typography variant='body2'>{service.starting_price} </Typography>
                      <Button
                        variant='outlined'
                        color='primary'
                        onClick={() => handleOpenModal(service)}
                        style={{ marginRight: 10 }}
                      >
                        Edit
                      </Button>
                      <Button variant='outlined' color='secondary' onClick={() => handleDeleteService(service.id)}>
                        Delete
                      </Button>
                    </CardContent>
                  </Card>
                </Grid>
              ))}
            </Grid>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>

        <Modal open={modalOpen} onClose={handleCloseModal}>
          <Box sx={modalStyle}>
            <Typography variant='h6' component='h2'>
              Service Details
            </Typography>
            {/* <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="Service Name"
            value={newService.name}
            onChange={(e) => setNewService({ ...newService, name: e.target.value })}
            margin="normal"
          />*/}
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              label='Service Details English'
              value={newService.details_en}
              onChange={e => setNewService({ ...newService, details_en: e.target.value })}
              margin='normal'
            />
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              label='Service Details Arabic'
              value={newService.details_ar}
              onChange={e => setNewService({ ...newService, details_ar: e.target.value })}
              margin='normal'
            />
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              label='Service Highlights English'
              value={newService.highlights_en}
              onChange={e => setNewService({ ...newService, highlights_en: e.target.value })}
              margin='normal'
            />
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              label='Service Highlights Arabic'
              value={newService.highlights_ar}
              onChange={e => setNewService({ ...newService, highlights_ar: e.target.value })}
              margin='normal'
            />
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              label='Starting Price'
              type='number'
              value={newService.starting_price}
              onChange={e => setNewService({ ...newService, starting_price: parseFloat(e.target.value) })}
              margin='normal'
            />
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              label='Minimum Time (mins)'
              type='number'
              value={newService.min_time_mins}
              onChange={e => setNewService({ ...newService, min_time_mins: parseFloat(e.target.value) })}
              margin='normal'
            />
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              label='Maximum Time (mins)'
              type='number'
              value={newService.max_time_mins}
              onChange={e => setNewService({ ...newService, max_time_mins: parseFloat(e.target.value) })}
              margin='normal'
            />
            <Select
              fullWidth
              value={selectedCategoryId}
              onChange={e => {
                const selectedCategory = categories.find(category => category.id === e.target.value)

                setSelectedCategoryId(e.target.value)
                setNewService({
                  ...newService,
                  category: {
                    ...newService.category,
                    name_en: selectedCategory.name_en,
                    name_ar: selectedCategory.name_ar
                  }
                })
              }}
              margin='normal'
            >
              <MenuItem value=''>
                <em>Select Category</em>
              </MenuItem>
              {categories.map(category => (
                <MenuItem key={category.id} value={category.id}>
                  {category.name_en} ({category.name_ar})
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Select>
            <Box mt={2}>
              <Button variant='contained' color='primary' onClick={handleSaveService}>
                Save Service
              </Button>
              <Button variant='outlined' color='secondary' onClick={handleCloseModal} style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
                Cancel
              </Button>
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </Modal>
      </Grid>
    )
  } else {
    ;<div>Loading ..</div>
  }
}

export default SaloonServices



stack trace references Firebase -  getImmediate and getOrInitializeService
I think firebase SDK is trying to access the 'navigator' object which is not available in the node.js environment
